# DPDK BBdev validation on LDPC ACC100

Tags: intel, dpdk

While running the BBdev test validations for our ACC100 5G BLER tasks, we found that our program stuck on

```
== test: validation

dev:cb:00.0, burst size: 32, num ops: 64, op type: RTE_BBDEV_OP_LDPC_DEC
```

First we followed the steps from pf-bb-config, we experience the following issues:

```
Baseband devices using DPDK-compatible driver
=============================================
0000:ca:00.0 'Device 0d5c' drv=vfio-pci unused=
0000:cb:00.0 'Device 0d5d' drv=vfio-pci unused=
0000:cb:00.1 'Device 0d5d' drv=vfio-pci unused=

zq40@tc319-srv2:/opt/dpdk-stable-21.11.2-older/app/test-bbdev$ dmesg | grep "DMAR: IOMMU"
[    0.457583] DMAR: IOMMU enabled
[    0.457977] DMAR: IOMMU enabled

zq40@tc319-srv2:/opt/dpdk-stable-21.11.2/app/test-bbdev/test_vectors$ sudo dpdk-test-bbdev -c F0 -a cb:00.0 --vfio-vf-token=00112233-4455-6677-8899-aabbccddeeff -- -c validation -v ldpc_dec_v2342_drop.data
[sudo] password for zq40:
EAL: Detected 56 lcore(s)
EAL: Detected 2 NUMA nodes
Option -w, --pci-whitelist is deprecated, use -a, --allow option instead
EAL: Detected static linkage of DPDK
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'VA'
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL:   using IOMMU type 1 (Type 1)
EAL: Probe PCI driver: intel_acc100_vf (8086:d5d) device: 0000:cb:00.0 (socket 1)
WARNING: Num of operations was not provided or was set 0. Set to default (64)
WARNING: Burst size was not provided or was set 0. Set to default (32)
WARNING: Num of lcores was not provided or was set 0. Set to value from RTE config (4)
===========================================================
Starting Test Suite : BBdev Validation Tests
Test vector file = ldpc_dec_v2342_drop.data
Device 0 supports 0 < N <= 0 queues, not 0
rte_bbdev_setup_queues(0, 0, 1) ret -22
Adding active bbdev cb:00.0 skipped
No suitable devices found!
 + Test suite setup BBdev Validation Tests skipped!
 + ------------------------------------------------------- +
```

We followed the pf_bb_config README and configured the ACC100 as directed by the tutorial, but it seems that the function fails when trying to set up queues.

The other thing we tried instead is to use igb_uio to drive our acc100 card,

```
sudo dpdk-devbind.py -b igb_uio ca:00.0
zq40@tc319-srv2:/opt/dpdk-stable-20.11.5/app/test-bbdev$ cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:ca\:00.0/sriov_totalvfs
16
echo 16 | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:ca\:00.0/max_vfs
echo 16 | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:ca\:00.0/sriov_numvfs
```

I tried both to configure the VFs through PF by both trying the vf/pf.cfg from the pf_bb_config. And we are able to avoid the previous error we saw when setting up the queues as:

```
zq40@tc319-srv2:/opt/dpdk-stable-20.11.5/app/test-bbdev$ sudo dpdk-test-bbdev -c F0 -a cb:00.0 --vfio-vf-token=00112233-4455-6677-8899-aabbccddeeff -- -c validation -v ./ldpc_dec_default.data

EAL: Detected 56 lcore(s)

EAL: Detected 2 NUMA nodes

EAL: Detected static linkage of DPDK

EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket

EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'

EAL: Probing VFIO support...

EAL: VFIO support initialized

EAL: Probe PCI driver: intel_acc100_vf (8086:d5d) device: 0000:cb:00.0 (socket 1)

WARNING: Num of operations was not provided or was set 0. Set to default (64)

WARNING: Burst size was not provided or was set 0. Set to default (32)

WARNING: Num of lcores was not provided or was set 0. Set to value from RTE config (4)


===========================================================

Starting Test Suite : BBdev Validation Tests

Test vector file = ./ldpc_dec_default.data

+ ------------------------------------------------------- +

== test: validation

dev:cb:00.0, burst size: 32, num ops: 64, op type: RTE_BBDEV_OP_LDPC_DEC
```

The test program just hung there with no progress.